# How can I do automation tests using real mobile devices in rails

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am using [webdriver-user-agent](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent) to perform a automation test in rails.

The available options are:

**:browser**

```
:firefox (default)
:chrome
```

**:agent**

```
:iphone (default)
:ipad
:android_phone
:android_tablet
```

**:orientation**

```
:portrait (default)
:landscape
```

How can i check the automation request using real mobile devices such as android/iphone/ipad,etc.

Comment: I don't think you can use watir for this

Answer (score 0):

That gem is used to mimic a device's resolution/user-agent for responsive design testing. You can't run tests on an actual device with it. If you want to test a web application on a mobile browser, webdriver-user-agent should be good enough.

For testing on a device, you'd need something like [Appium](http://appium.io).